# 16.04 No Driver for Integrated Webcam

Tags: drivers, 16.04, webcam

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and my integrated webcam is no longer working.
From what I can tell, it's completely missing a driver.

Below are the results of `lsusb -t`.

`/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M`

As you can see, the driver is clearly missing. If I press `fn+f6` *(my webcam hotkey)* to toggle off webcam and run `lsusb -t` again then associated lines completely disappear *(as they should)*.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Laptop Model #: `GP70 2PE` *(No official Linux support, but webcam worked fine on 14.04)*

Comment: May we see`lsusb` without the `-t` modifier, so that we can see the usb.id?

Answer (score 0):

If your webcam required the use of a third party driver, 16.04 requires the use of all drivers to be signed with a key. You can get around this by turning off secure boot in your BIOS.

To check for a driver, go to terminal and type "dkms status". List any output here. If it says dkms not found, then there's no driver installed this way.

You can also open "Software & Updates" from the dash, and check the additional drivers tab.

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?